# What is the value of vector members in Qt Creator's debugger?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, pointers

I have two classes. One is a container.

First class:

```
class node
{
private:
    node *left, *right, *parent;
public:
    node(node* parent,node* left,node* right);
    virtual ~node() {cout<<"~node()"<<endl;}
};
```

Second class has a vector of pointers to the first class:

```
class tree
{
public:
    vector<node*> nodes;
public:
    tree(int size);
    ~tree();

    void showPointers();

};

void tree::showPointers()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++)
    {
        cout<<"nodes["<<i<<"] = "<<nodes[i]<<endl;
    }
}
```

I am creating one object tree with size: 5 and looking addresses of every vector nodes member.

```
int main()
{
    tree d(5);

    d.showPointers();

    cout<<"end"<<endl;

}
```

In terminal I see (what showPointers shows):

[image: terminal output from <code>showPointers</code>]

The debugger shows:

[image: debugger variable pane]

What are these addresses from the debugger's variable pane?

```
@0x9dea0b8
@0x9dea0bc
@0x9dea0c0
@0x9dea0c4
@0x9dea0c8
```

I expected that they will be the same as the pointers I store in the `nodes` vector.

Comment: what happens in the constructor of Tree?

Comment: cout<<"tree()"<<endl;
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
       nodes.push_back( new node(NULL,NULL,NULL) );

Comment: You are creating new pointers and put them into vector. Afterwards you iterate over this vector and print them out. Why do you expect they should be the same?

Comment: in debugger they should be the same as in terminal, but someone has already answered me on this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addresses that you see are the addresses of where the values are stored. These addresses have nothing to do with what is a value - it's only a coincidence that your values are pointers. The debugger output would be the same had you used `std::vector<intptr_t>` instead of `std::vector<node*>`.

In your case, the expression `&nodes[0]` had value `(node**)0x9dea0b8`, etc.

You need to expand each of the `[n]` tree items to see their values - the values of the pointers that you store.

Comment: Thanks, cout<<&nodes[0]<<endl; etc shows the same addresses as in debugger. So this addresses are addresses to the pointers to node?

Comment: @user3191398 These are addresses of where your values (your pointers) are stored inside of the vector. Their type is `node**` (pointer to a pointer to node).

Comment: But for what are these addresses? For example if i had int* i; &i points to i which points to value of i? For what is &i address?

Comment: One more question. If i do http://wklej.org/id/1774986/, in debugger it shows me value of i - *i[0] not &i[0]. So why in previous example it shows &node[0]?

Comment: @user3191398 If you have `int * i`, then `&i` points to *a pointer to int*. That's `i`'s type. So, for example you can have `int val = 10; int * i = &val; **i = 20; assert(val == 20);`

Comment: @user3191398 It has only to do with what debugging information is emitted for a particular instance of the vector type. Whenever you see `@something`, just ignore it and click the `[+]` on the left to dig deeper.